# Angular: Get origin after navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Goodday,

I have the following (simple) problem. I have 2 components navigating to 1 component in the one component I want to know from which component the navigation came so I can act accordingly (refresh list or not in this case). Problem is the url is the same at both components.

```
// Component: ToolbarComponent
// URL: /products/123
navigateBack() {
  this.router.navigate(['/products']);    
}
```

-

```
// Component: ProductDetailComponent
// URL: /products/123
navigateBack() {
  this.router.navigate(['/products']);    
}
```

-

```
// Component: ProductsComponent
// URL: /products
public constructor() {
  this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd && 
            e.urlAfterRedirects.endsWith('products')) {
            // Here i want to know the origin, ToolbarComponent or ProductDetailComponent
        }
}
```

I think the above simplified code gives a good example of what I want to accomplish.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I dont want the origin to be visible in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Suresh offered, you can use queryParams. The issue with this solution is that it will pollute the URL with unecessary params.

What you can instead do is use a sharing service, where you will store the caller :

```js
export class SharingService {
  ...
  navigateBack(caller: any) {
    this.caller = caller;
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);    
  }
}
```

In your components :

```js
navigateBack() {
  this.sharingService.navigateBack(this);    
}
```

You can now, in your previous component, test if the caller is an instance of either components :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.sharingService.caller instanceof ComponentOne) { ... }
  else if (this.sharingService.caller instanceof ComponentTwo) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this should do the job, I tried to not use a service cause it seems like a bit of overkill to do such a simple job.

Comment: The purpose of services is to handle this kind of communication between components. But your project, your choice, glad you resovled your issue

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to angular so have to get in the right mindset.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle using query params or service class will will track from where user came from?.

this._router.navigate(['/products'], { queryParams: { from:'viewname' } });

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, I don want it to be visible in the url

Comment: Then you can follow service approach.  Create a property set the value before redirecting access in the service value in the required place